# Term for a website with editorial board

Tags: terminology

Is there a word for a website with staff members who produce all or the main content (can be articles, podcasts, video, art and so on)? Stack Exchange is an entirely community-driven website, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it a **juried** or **paneled** site, even if it has a jury of one. Point is, the site has some judging going on behind the scenes.

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language (Fifth Edition):](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/juried)

**Jury**--A committee that judges contestants or applicants, as in a competition or exhibition; a panel of judges.
tr.v. **ju·ried**, ju·ry·ing, ju·ries - To judge or evaluate by a jury.

**Panel**--Those persons chosen...to constitute a pool from which a jury...will be selected for a particular court. A group of people gathered to plan or discuss an issue, judge a contest, or act as a team on a radio or television quiz program.